# Cant use SavePreferences for TextView

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, savestate

I have a TextView. When the Activity is first created the Value of the textView is "", as in nothing. But the user can initiate some actions that can make the text="st". That works fine, once more that works fine. The problem is when I leave the page and come back instead of text="st" ,  it's " " as in nothing. So the user has to waste time and get the textView back to "st" through some actions.

I tried to save the TextView using SavePreferences but since the value of TextView is nothing when the activity starts SavePreferences does exactly what it's supposed to do and makes the TextView equal nothing. Isn't there some way for me to save the value of the TextView. I have other Views on my page I do not want to save, so how do I save just the TextView as it is when the user leaves the app or activity?

```
TextView s1;
s1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.s1);

//9 miles down the page
LoadPreferences();
SavePreferences("MEM46", s1.getText().toString());

LoadPreferences();} 
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();}

private void LoadPreferences(){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String strSavedMem46 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM46", "");
s1.setText(strSavedMem46);

lay1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
public boolean onLongClick(View v){

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(xxx.this);
alert.setTitle("Help"); //Set Alert dialog title here
alert.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int choice){ 

if(choice == 0) {
d.cancel();
}
else if(choice == 1){
TextView ss1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.s1);
 ss1.setText("st");d.cancel();                                                                                                           } 
 else if(choice == 2)                                                                   {
 TextView ss1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.s1);
 ss1.setText("");d.cancel();}});
 alert.show();
 return true;                                                                             

 }});
```

Comment: are Load and Save Preferences in the same activity?

Comment: Yes they are on the same activity.

Comment: you can add a button to your layout and when you press on it you call SaveSharedPreference. Are you sure you need a TextView and not an EditText?

Comment: It's too small to be an EditText. I open a dialog that allows user to decide to put "st" in the TextView. It's just barely big enough for the user to see.

Comment: I could use a button but I think my user would forget to press Save and I'm trying to make it easy for them.

Comment: when u open the dialog and the user decides to enter the string st on that moment y dont u set it in shared pref

Comment: The TextView is a read only EditText. How the use can enter a string ? Also what does "enter" mean ?

Comment: In the AlertDialog they don't write "st". They choose a button that puts "st" in the TextView. They can choose another button to remove it now or later.

Comment: when they press the button call SaveSharedPreference, what's the matter?

Comment: Android28 How do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use `et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){...}`??

Comment: OMG..I feel like the biggest dummy in the world. One single line of SavePreferences("MEM46", s1.getText().toString()); and it works. I'm going to go sit in the corner now and be quiet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At which point exactly do you call LoadPreferences/SavePreferences?

Saving should happen only when the user leaves the activity, so onPause() must be overriden to call the savePreference(). Loading should be done in onStart().

Comment: Saving should happen only when the user leaves the activity...That was very useful. Thank you.